# Why isn't for /f working in this batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, scripting

I'm trying to capture the output of a command in a batch script with `for /f`. Here is my code:

```
set RUNPS="powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command"
set OLDPATHPS="[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')"
for /f %%i in ('%RUNPS% %OLDPATHPS%') do ^
    set OLDPATH=%%i
```

When I run the script from the console, here is the output:

```
C:\Users\James\Downloads>testscript
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
...
```

On the other hand, when I run the command normally I get

```
C:\Users\James\Downloads>powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')"
C:\Users\James\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin;C:\Users\James\.dnx\bin;...
```

Why does this happen with `for /f` and what can I do to fix it?

---

**EDIT:** Thought it may have been an issue with the single quotes being unescaped. Tried using usebackq:

```
for /f usebackq %%i in (`%RUNPS% %OLDPATHPS%`) do ^
    set OLDPATH=%%i
```

But it looks like I'm getting the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "RUNPS=powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command"
set "OLDPATHPS=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('%RUNPS% "%OLDPATHPS%"') DO (
    set OLDPATH=%%i
)
SET o

GOTO :EOF
```

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

The required syntax for the command is

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')"
```

not

```
"powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command" "[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')"
```

The `' ' is not recognized ...` message appears to be the consequence of attempting to use the caret. It appears to be invalid as you've used it - I've never seen that ateempted before.

Note that you need the "delims=" to ensure that a user-path-containing-spaces is not tokenised.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you escape the linebreak after do? You should use:

```
set RUNPS="powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command"
set OLDPATHPS="[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')"
for /f %%i in ('%RUNPS% %OLDPATHPS%') do (
set OLDPATH=%%i
)
```

Note that if you want to use variables like OLDPATH inside a for loop (after the do) you have to use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top of your script, and use `!` instead of `%` for variables inside the loop

EDIT: your powershell currently has this exception:

> -Command : The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a
>   path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - -Command [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')
> - ~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Command:String) [], CommandNot
>       FoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Thanks! It looks like your suggestion got rid of that error, but now `OLDPATH` is being set to a `+` for some reason. Could you please help?

Comment: Your powershell command has an exception. Look at my updated answer

Comment: Using the syntax `set "OLDPATH=%%i"` avoids many troubles with special characters...

Comment: @DennisvanGils Hmm... it seems to be failing even when I remove `-Command`.

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If I may ask, why do you use powershell to get an environment variable? Is it part of the assignment, because batch can access environment variables itself. For a list of all of them, type `SET` in cmd, because I don't think User exists

Comment: @DennisvanGils I'm trying to append a string to PATH for only the current user via `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable` and `SetEnvironmentVariable`, and unfortunately it looks like PowerShell is the only way to do it.

Comment: In that case I suggest creating a new question with the powershell tag where you ask for the correct code to do that.